# How to get next value if exists in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `A` as foolows:

```
id name      nextid    orderset
19  done               4
21  init       27      1
24  sent-req   19      3
27  offer-req  24      2
```

the `orderset` column gives me the order of the status: `init -> offer-req -> sent-req -> done`

I need to write a query that for a given `id`, it gives the `id` of the next status.

That should be easy:

```
select id
from A
where orderset= (select orderset+1 from A where id=Any_Given_ID)
```

That works in all cases except the last id... as there is no next to `id=19`, In the case of the last one I want the query to return `0`.

I thought of doing a check with `Max(orderset)` and `select order+1 from A where id=Any_Given_ID` but I just can't seem to make it work.

Is it doable in a query or do I have to write a function for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the orders are consecutive, just use `lead()`:

```
select id
from (select coalesce(lead(id) over (order by orderset), 0) as id
      from A
     ) a
where id = Any_Given_ID;
```

You can also use your method *with aggregation*.  That guarantees that one row is returned:

```
select coalesce(max(id), 0)
from A
where orderset = (select orderset + 1 from A where id = Any_Given_ID);
```

Comment: I'm confused... The reason I didn't though of using coalesce(something, 0), is because if first argument exists it always return him. So why would it return 0? max(id) exists.

Comment: @John . . . If the `where` clause has no matches, then the `max()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: thx. Can you also explain the lead example? The postgresql manual says: "returns value evaluated at the row that is offset rows after the current row within the partition" it's not very clear.

Comment: @John . . . There is no partition, so the entire data set is used.  It gets the next value based on `orderset`.